# Content does not appear after entering php code

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to implement a code to get an initial user name from my database, I put the code in the header section, the problem is that after I input the code the content on my page doesn't appear. Is there something wrong with my code below?

```
<div class="symbol symbol-light-success btn-dropdown">
     <?php
      function getProfilePicture($name)
     {
       $name_slice = explode(' ', $name);
       $name_slice = array_filter($name_slice);
       $initials = '';
       $initials .= (isset($name_slice[0][0])) ? strtoupper($name_slice[0][0]) : '';
       $initials .= (isset($name_slice[count($name_slice) - 1][0])) ? strtoupper($name_slice[count($name_slice) - 1][0]) : '';
       return '<span class="symbol-label display-5">' . $initials . '</span>';
     }
    ?>
    <?php echo getProfilePicture($_SESSION['username']);?>
```

Answer (score 1):

check your php errors with add this code to first line of file

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

and check error of code
maybe is from

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine. You can tested by using:

```php
<?php echo getProfilePicture($_SESSION['username'] ?? 'Hello World');?>
// output: HW
```

It seems that you dont have username in you session or is empty or you forgot to start the session: `session_start();`. In the last case:  Add `<?php session_start(); ?>` on top in your script.

Comment: Sory, this happened due to my negligence, now the code is working. thanks very much.

Comment: @Andri Cool! If the answer helped you to find this bug, i would be happy if you give me an UpVote. If the hint helped to solve the problem, an accept would be very nice. so later visitors can see what to look out for. Thank you very much!